# indian railway child issue

Tags: indian-railways

I had booked a ticket for travel through Indian Railways using IRCTC and got a confirmed ticket. While booking, I mentioned the details of a four year old child who will also be traveling.but it does not get mentioned in ticket anywhere.

Will it create any problem while boarding the train?

Comment: Did you pay for a seat or berth for the child?

Answer (score 0):

From April 2016, You can carry children below 5 for free (without berth i.e. you won't get additional seat for your child). Quoting for [official source](http://pib.nic.in/newsite/PrintRelease.aspx?relid=132573)

> Children under five years of age will continue to be carried free (without berth).

However, if child is between 5 to 12 years, half price if you DO NOT want additional seat OR full price if you DO want additional seat.

> full adult fare will be charged for children of age 5 years and under
>   12 years of age if for whom berth/seat (in reserved class) is sought
>   at the time of reservation. However, in case berth/seat is not sought
>   for the children of age 5 years and under 12 years of age at the time
>   of reservation,  then half of the adult fare shall continue to be
>   charged subject to the minimum distance for charging.

It is a good idea to take some birth proof (like birth certificate) to prove that your kid is under 5 years.